# Is there a way when parsing XML in Python to ignore DTD in XML and use a local DTD file instead?

Tags: python, xml, evernote

Returning to learning Python after long absence.

I have a question about something I'm doing to solve another problem. I'll list both problems in case my initial problem has a better solution than what I'm trying.

I have written code to parse Evernote's ENEX file which is XML.

[Evernote's ENEX's documentation](https://evernote.com/blog/how-evernotes-xml-export-format-works/#:%7E:text=The%20ENEX%20file%20format%20is%20formally%20defined%20by,all%20attached%20files%2C%20recognition%20information%20and%20tags%20%28optionally%29.)

I'm getting this error :

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Entity 'nbsp' not defined, line 68908, column 61176
```

for this code

```
mytree = ET.parse(PATH TO THE ENEX FILE)
```

So I copied the DTD    http://xml.evernote.com/pub/evernote-export3.dtd
to a local file and added an Entity to convert nbsp to a space.

I don't want to have to edit each ENEX file I parse with the new DTD.

Is there a way to tell it to ignore the DTD mentioned in the ENEX file and instead use one with path I provide?

Comment: I think you will find an answer [in lxml docu](https://lxml.de/validation.html#id1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an *XML catalog*.

The following catalog file (let's call it catalog.xml) contains a `system` entry that says "whenever the parser encounters `http://xml.evernote.com/pub/evernote-export3.dtd`, use `local-evernote-export3.dtd` instead":

```xml
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog">
  <system systemId="http://xml.evernote.com/pub/evernote-export3.dtd"
          uri="local-evernote-export3.dtd"/>
</catalog>
```

Here is Python code that ensures that the catalog file is consulted:

```
import os
from lxml import etree

os.environ["XML_CATALOG_FILES"] = "catalog.xml"
parser = etree.XMLParser(load_dtd=True)
tree = etree.parse(PATH TO THE ENEX FILE, parser=parser)
```

More information:

- https://xmlcatalogs.org/catalogs-1.1.html
- https://lxml.de/resolvers.html#xml-catalogs

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that after Father's Day festivities.  Looks like exactly what I was looking for.